# Method to view "Flickr best of the day" images as a screensaver?

Tags: images, rss, screensaver, flickr

Looking for a method to display the "best of the day" images from Flickr or Google Images, as a screensaver.

I've heard that a Media RSS viewer might do the trick - any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this one? [Flickr .Net Screensaver](http://flickrnetscreensaver.codeplex.com/)

A blog post featuring the above app: [How To View Flickr Photos As Screensaver In Windows](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-view-flickr-photos-as-screensaver-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it with [Screensaver Ninja](https://screensaver.ninja). They currently have a version for Mac OS X and apparently they are also making one for Windows. It can display any web site, so you can display Flickr or Google Images. They have an explanation on how to do it with Flickr here: https://screensaver.ninja/knowledge-base/flickr-slideshow/

Comment: This is Pablo from Screensaver Ninja. This just popped up in my feed and yes, this is correct, you can use it to display Flickr and any website you want.